# What is the limiting distribution of the Monte Carlo estimate of a log-mixed-normal distribution?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, monte-carlo

Assume $x \sim N(\mu_x,\sigma_x^2)$, $y \sim N(\mu_y,\sigma_y^2)$, and

\begin{equation*}
    z= 
    \begin{cases} x & \text{with probability } \alpha
    \\
    y &\text{otherwise}    \end{cases} \text{s.t } \alpha \in (0,1).
    \end{equation*}

Consider a Monte Carlo simulation over $N$ draws of $z$, $Z_N := \{ z_n : n \in \{ 1,\cdots , N\} \}$ of the moment,

\begin{equation*}
X := E[\exp{\{z\}}],
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
X^{mc}_N = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N \exp{\{z_n\}}.
\end{equation*}

As I understand it, according to the Fundamental Theorem of Monte Carlo Integration, the error is approximately distributed

\begin{equation*}
X^{mc}_N \sim N(X,V_N/N) \\ \text{ s.t. } \\ V_N = \frac{1}{N-1} \sum_{n=1}^N [exp\{z_n\} - X_N^{mc}]^2.
\end{equation*}.

My question is if there is a known correction to this theorem that accounts for the fact that $X$ is bounded below by 0, since it is the exponential tranformation of a variable whose support is $(-\infty,\infty)$?

It seems to me that if $E[X]$ is close enough to 0 relative to $\frac{V_N}{N}$, the distribution of $X^{mc}_N$ should be a Rectified Normal Distribution. Am I correct? Is there any research touching on this matter?

Comment: This is the plain Central Limit Theorem isn't it?

Comment: Corrected. And yes, this is the plain CLT. Is the answer that there are weaker forms of the CLT that accounts for what I am getting at?

Comment: The (plain) CLT applies to random variables with a support equal to $\mathbb R^+$. Or to $\mathbb N$. Or to $(0,1)$.